# How to get Databricks Account ID without logging in to Account console?

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-service-principal, databricks-unity-catalog

I want to create Unity Catalogue with service principle using Terraform, but the provider to access account level requires account ID -

```
provider "databricks" {
  host = "https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net"
  account_id = "???????" // How to get this?
}
```

I can get the account ID from the account console as per MS documentation - [locate account ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/#--locate-your-account-id). But, I want to know if there is a way to get the same thru code? So that everything is managed as code.